# How to deal with data when making a decision tree

Tags: classification, data-mining, decision-tree, data-science, kaggle

I am trying to make a decision tree for dataset I got from Kaggle.
Since I don't have any experience for dealing with real-life datasets, I have no idea how to deal with cleaning, integrating, and scaling the data (mainly scaling).

For example, let's say I have a feature that has real numbers. So I want to make that feature to something like categorical data by scaling them into the specific number of groups (for making decision tree).

In this case, I have no idea how many groups of data is a reasonable for decision tree purpose. 
I am sure it depends on the distribution of the data for the feature and the number of unique values in target dataset but I don't know how I find the good guess by looking at the distribution and target dataset.
My best guess is divide the data of the feature into similar number with the number of unique values of target dataset. (I don't even know if this makes sense..)

When I learned from school, I was already given with 2-5 categorical data for every features so that I didn't have to worry about, but real-life is totally different from school.

Please help me out.

Comment: Real life classification could be really tight. With the situation that lack labels, you could also take unsupervised learning as a consideration.

Answer (score 2):

1. For DT you need numerical data to be numerical, categorical - to be in dummies-style. No scaling is needed for numerical columns.
2. To process categorical data use one-hot encoding. Please be sure that before one-hot encoding you have rather big amounts of each feature (>= 5%), otherwise group small variables.
3. And consider other model. DT are good but it's old school and they are easy to be overfitted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use decision tree regressors which eliminate the need for stratifying real numbers in to categories: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html

When you do this, it will help to scale input data to zero mean, and unit variance; this helps prevent any large-category inputs from dominating the model

That being said, a decision tree may not be the best option.  Try SVM, or ANN.  Or (most likely) some ensemble of many models (or even just a random forest).

Comment: Yes, it makes sense to scale input data to zero mean and unit variance. Thanks!